# Ubuntu 15.10 and BCM43142

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, 15.10, broadcom

I have a problem with my new HP 250 G4 notebook or better with the included wireless card and Ubuntu 15.10:

When I'm near the wlan router it takes about 5s to connect to my network. At places with weaker wlan signal, it can take up to 3minutes to connect. Once connected, it works normally at places with good wlan. At places with weak signal websites often need to be reloaded (F5).

Strange thing: After the endless search for wlan it says “Disconnected from network” and at the next second it is connected.

It is no hardware problem because the same hardware with Win7 works perfectly at all places.

“lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net” tells me it is a  Boradcom BCM43142, using the Broadcom-802.11-Linux-STA driver

Short:

- Ubuntu 15.10
- HP 250 G4
- Intel Core i3
- BCM43142 @ M.2
- Broadcom-802.11-Linux-STA driver

Anyone any idea?